# Copying 1-D array into 2 -D array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

I have one two dimensional array and one single dimensional array.
The two dimensional array is of NxM size. And the one dimensional array is of size N x M means
it has N X M elements.

Now I want to copy all the elements of the one dimensional array into the 2-D array.

This is what I tried

```
for(i = 0; i < M; i += 1) {
        for(j = 0; j < N; j += 1) {
            arr2d[i][j] = arr2d[(i*j +j)];
        }
}
```

But not working Any suggestions???

Comment: Why is this tagged as `java`, `javascript` and `c`?

Comment: I tagged java and others if solution can be provided in any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr1d = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var M = 1, N = 2;
var arr2d = [];
var counter = 0;
for(i = 0; i <= M; i += 1) {
    for(j = 0; j <= N; j += 1) {
        if(j == 0)
            arr2d[i] = [];
        arr2d[i][j] = arr1d[counter++];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change:

```
arr2d[i][j] = arr2d[(i*j +j)];
```

to:

```
arr2d[i][j] = arr1d[(i*N + j)];
```

which would probably work out better.